# Issue filter and using Object.entries

Tags: javascript, json, filter

I have the following issue. I have a code that if I put it separate chaining the `.filters` it works, also if I test the code separtly, but when I combine them even when the values are returning true they are not being return so I think I'm not applying correctly the `returns` inside of the `ifs`

**THIS DOESN'T WORK**

```js
    const FILTERED_DATA = this.filteredProjects.filter(o => {
      Object.entries(FORM_VALUES).every(([k, v]) => {
        if (isDate(sC) || isDate(eC)) {
          if (this.dateRangeValidator(sC, eC, o.created)) {
            return v === "" || o[k] === v || v === 0 || v === "Invalid Date";
          }
        } else if (isDate(sM) || isDate(eM)) {
          if (this.dateRangeValidator(sM, eM, o.modified)) {
            return v === "" || o[k] === v || v === 0 || v === "Invalid Date";
          }
        } else {
          return true;
        }
      });
    });
```

**WORKS**

```js
    const FILTERED_DATA = this.filteredProjects
      .filter(o => {
        if (isDate(sC) || isDate(eC)) {
          return this.dateRangeValidator(sC, eC, o.created);
        } else if (isDate(sM) || isDate(eM)) {
          return this.dateRangeValidator(sM, eM, o.modified);
        } else {
          return true;
        }
      })
      .filter(o =>
        Object.entries(FORM_VALUES).every(
          ([k, v]) => v === "" || o[k] === v || v === 0 || v === "Invalid Date"
        )
      );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `return`

```
const FILTERED_DATA = this.filteredProjects
        .filter(o => {
            return Object.entries(FORM_VALUES)
//          ^^^^^^
```

and omit return `true` at the end.

Comment: When I did that it was returning the entire array, like it wasn't filtering

Comment: I can create a stackbliz if necessary. I have been trying to solve this for several hours. every helps is appreciated.

Comment: maybe you need to remove the last `return true`.

Comment: I just figured that out before I saw your comment. hahah I'm so dumb! thanks so much